# Logs for Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor, automated-tests, nodes

I am new to protractor and want to create logs for my test cases. I used if and else to write logs. I wanted to know if there is any better way of writing logs for protractor test cases?

My Code:

```
var colors = require('colors/safe');

var mapFeedBackpage=require('./mapFeedBack-page.js')
describe("Map feedback Automation",function()
{

var mapFeedBack= new mapFeedBackpage();

    it("Check if the Url works ",function() //spec1
    {
        console.log("Checking the url :"+browser.params.url+'\n')
        browser.get(browser.params.url);
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(value){
  if(/report/.test(value) === false) {
    fail("Result: URL doesnt works-FAIL \n");
  }
  else
  {
      console.log(colors.green("PASS :")+browser.params.url+ "is reachable \n");
  }

});

    }); 


    it("test browser should reach report road option",function() //spec2s
    {
        console.log("Checking if road report option is available \n");
        mapFeedBack.REPORT_ROAD.click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("report_road");
        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(value){

        if(/report_road/.test(value) === false) {
        fail("Result: URL doesnt works-FAIL");
  }
  else
  {
      console.log(colors.green("PASS")+" Road report option is available");
  }

});

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js which is basically log4j module for nodejs apps. Since protractor is nodejs program it would certainly support this. It's very easy to implement this-

```
 var log4js = require('log4js');
 var logger = log4js.getLogger();
 logger.debug("Some debug messages");
```

or you could write a **custom logger:**

```
 var logger = exports;
logger.debugLevel = 'warn';
logger.log = function(level, message) {
var levels = ['error', 'warn', 'info'];
if (levels.indexOf(level) >= levels.indexOf(logger.debugLevel) ) {
  if (typeof message !== 'string') {
    message = JSON.stringify(message);
  };
  console.log(level+': '+message);
}
 }
```

and then use this in your scripts as :

```
var logger = require('./logger');
logger.debugLevel = 'warn';
logger.log('info', 'Everything started properly.');
logger.log('warn', 'Running out of memory...');
logger.log('error', { error: 'flagrant'});
```

Comment: Also can you tell me a good IDE to use for node.js and protractor program?

Comment: Visual Studio Code - https://code.visualstudio.com/ it is the best editor for nodejs

Comment: You can also use **Webstorm** it has a protractor plugin as well, but I personally use VSCode :)